# Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -8). Message: b' in odoo 12 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, ubuntu-18.04, odoo-12

I have tried to install wkhtml2pdf in odoo12 in ubuntu 18.04  but i could not get the report.and I can't uninstall the wkhtmltopdf

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have also a problem like Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -8) only when I wanted to send-email or print, but I managed to overcome this as:
1. First, go to `/opt/odoo12/odoo` folder. 
2. Now, Install wkhtmltopdf as,`sudo apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf` 
3. Stop and start odoo server.

Try this once, if it might help you solve this problem.